# Bootstrap file-input does not call the controller method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-file-input

I am new to Laravel. I am using Bootstrap file-input plugin to upload multiple files in Laravel. But in my code, url in the uploadUrl is not called. That means ajax call is not sent to the laravel backend controller and controller method is not called. Could you please help me in resolving this issue? Thank you.

HTML CODE

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label required">FEATURED IMAGES</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="featured-file" name="featured-file[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
<p class="notice">Please use to upload 550px width x 670px height images for better view</p>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code

```
$("#featured-file").fileinput({  
        theme: 'fa',
        uploadAsync:true,
        uploadUrl:"{{ url('/news/uploadimgsaddmode') }}",
        uploadExtraData: function() {
           return {
              _token: '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
           };
        },            
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif','jpeg'],
        overwriteInitial: false,
        maxFileSize:2000,
        maxFilesNum: 10
        }).on('fileuploaded', function(event, previewId, index, fileId) {
            console.log('File Uploaded', 'ID: ' + fileId + ', Thumb ID: ' + previewId);
        }).on('fileuploaderror', function(event, data, msg) {
            console.log('File Upload Error', 'ID: ' + data.fileId + ', Thumb ID: ' + data.previewId);
});
```

```
Laravel Controller Method

public function uploadimagesaddmode(Request $request){
        Session::put('uploaded_files','Hi');
        Session::save();
        return response()->json(['uploaded' =>'Hi']);
}
```

And I used some html code to test whether controller method is called or not

```html
<p>@if(Session::has('uploaded_files')) {{ Session::get('uploaded_files') }} @endif</p>
```

If controller method is called Session values should be printed. But no value is printed.

Comment: Don't forget that by default you also need to send a **_csrf** token in your POST request. [More about CSRF in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Thepeanut. I edited the code but still not working.

Comment: Can you also post the result you get in browser's source code viewer?

Comment: @Thepeanut do you mean the full source code of the page? or the result in the browser console?

Comment: The resulting html + javascript code in your browser.

Comment: Sorry can't post it. Stackoverflow says "Too many characters to post"

Comment: wheres your web.php or api.php

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'news', 'namespace' => 'NewsManage\Http\Controllers'], function(){  Route::post('uploadimgsaddmode',[
        'as'=>'news.uploadimgsaddmode','uses'=>'NewsController@uploadimagesaddmode'
      ]);     

    });
}); @TobyOkeke

Comment: Where did you write the html view? You are returning json and then using html to try to access the response of your post. Your expected response should be "Hi" in the console of your browser in the "onfileuploaded" function.

Comment: @TobyOkeke <p>@if(Session::has('uploaded_files')) {{ Session::get('uploaded_files') }} @endif</p> If controller method is called Session values should be printed. But no value is printed.

Comment: This is not how the session works. PHP is not asynchronous, and the browser session is not changed unless there is a redirect. If you're doing an ajax request, the browser itself can have the new session value, but you're echoing it using PHP.
Try refreshing the page after the JS ajax call to see if the session is stored anywhere.

Comment: I refreshed the page and session data is not stored. @AndréTzermias

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Thanks for all who responded to my question :)

I edited the jQuery Code. Here's the edited one. It works for me.

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
        $("#featured-file").fileinput({  
            theme: 'fa',
            allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif','jpeg'],              
            uploadUrl: "{{ url('news/uploadimgsaddmode') }}", 
            uploadExtraData: function() {
                return {
                    _token: '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>',

                };
            },
            uploadAsync:true,           
            overwriteInitial: false,
            maxFileSize:2000,
            maxFilesNum: 10,                       
        }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {
            $("#featured-file").fileinput("upload");
        });
    });
```